# How do I execute an adobe air app from Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, communication

How do I execute an Adobe Air app & pass arguments from Flex ?

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I'm assuming you're talking about launching from a Flex application running in Flash Player.

[This page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/distributing_apps_3.html) discusses launching from a browser.  I think the last section, "Launching an installed AIR application from the browser" applies most closely to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new flex project you must select in the "Application type" the "Desktop application" option. Then when you run your project, this will be displayed in a flash window.
When you have an error, sometimes you have to "kill" the Air Debug Launcher from the task manager to compile and execute the project. Hope this answer will be useful.
Bye.